# Cannot boot Ubuntu - Black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, graphics

Last night all worked very well, but after i shut down my computer it won't boot to Ubuntu.

I am using dual boot of Ubuntu 15.10 and Kali Linux 2.0, in kali it boots just fine but after selecting Ubuntu on boot menu it proceeds and stops on black screen.

I don't have any informations on anything neither i can collect any of them because i can't see anything. Is that graphics problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it you may have in inadvertently tampered with the linux-image related files inside of /boot. I know there was a security update yesterday (21-1-2016) for 15.10 which included a patchlevel update (4.2.0-25) to the 4.2 kernel (the default kernal for Wily) to address the key ring exploit.

Your first port of call may be to, from within your working Linux build: download Ubuntu 15.10 http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop, create a bootable USB.  Then boot to USB (you may have to alter BIOS boot settings depending upon your setup) and see if you can then inspect the partition that you have Ubuntu 15.10 installed on (namely /boot.).

Comment: I tryed to enter the terminal in additional options / recovery mode and reinstalled my graphics driver and now it's not black it's loading Ubuntu and it stops on that (screen with Ubuntu logo and dots for loading) any suggestion now? Beside reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: Aside from effectively trying to "rebuild" (cross refernce its contents with that of a working one) that /boot directory (assuming you can access it via the LiveCD) you may want to think about a clean install. Either way, I would recommend getting that bootable USB and having it at hand at all times just in case you need it. At this point it may even be more time efficient to do a clean install assuming you do not have any critical files within that installation and you do not mind reinstalling a couple peices of software (as it is 15.10 I can't imagine these being too time consuming).

Comment: I've done that, i did not want to waste time any more on that. I've accessed (because i have dual boot) files i want to keep from other system (namely Kali) and reinstalled ubuntu (clean) on that partition where the ubuntu was in the first place. I would recommend this to everyone with similair problems because i've discovered some other issues and that all was fixed, of course, with clean install. Thanks for the reply.